# Clojure : what am I missing from comp?

Tags: clojure, function-composition

I'm currenthly trying to work with `comp`and it looks like I am missing something.
If I understand well, comp works in the same order as the mathematical composition, so (comp g f) is like g(f(x)).

Imagine I have a map like that

```
(def m {:a 1 :b nil :c 3})
```

I would like to use `remove` with a short `nil-key?` function to remove the entries which have nil values, so :

```
(into {} (remove nil-key? m)) = {:a 1 :c 3}
```

I tried to define nil-key? like that :

```
(defn nil-key? []
  (comp nil? second))
```

It returns an empty map (if I use filter, no map entry is removed)

Maybe I do not understand how the `remove` function works because I thught there was an hidden `map`.

Like : 1) first map second on the hashmap
       2) tells if the value is nil
       3) give the matching

I could do

```
(into {} (filter second m))
```

But is also removes `false`, which I want not.

Of course I can do it easily with a different approach but I would like to understand the `comp` function.

Thanks !

**EDIT**

The answer

```
(def nil-key?
  (comp nil? second))
```

The final function

```
(defn remove-nil-keys [map]
  (->> (remove nil-key? map)
       (into {})))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake in your `nil-key?` definition. Your function returns a function that will produce a composed function:

```
(defn nil-key? []
  (comp nil? second))
```

If you want to use it in this form you would have to call `nil-key?` in order to produce your predicate function:

```
(into {} (remove (nil-key?) m))
;; => {:a 1, :c 3}
```

Instead you should define a var with the result of composing the functions:

```
(def nil-key? (comp nil? second))
```

Then it will work correctly:

```
(into {} (remove nil-key? m))
;; => {:a 1, :c 3}
```

Comment: Oh yes I did not even think about that, I used defn because "pragmatically" it's a function but programatically this seems logic, thanks !